# Retain the value of a random generated number

Tags: php

I am learning php atm and i decided to make a simple game but now im confronted with a problem. I have the following code:

```
<form action="wolf.php" method="POST">
<input type="submit" value="Attack" name="submit"/> <br />
<?php
    $hp = 100;
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $attack = $_POST['submit'];
        $damage = mt_rand(5, 30);
        $newhp = $hp - $damage;
        if ($attkdamage = $hp - $damage ) {
            echo "Your HP is:  ". $newhp .  "<br / >";
            echo "You took: " . $damage . " damage!";
        }
    }
?>
```

As you can see I have a variable with an integer (100) and a simple mt rand. What I want is that after I submit and get a $newhp (100 - the random number), that number to replace $hp. and the next time I submit the button I want the value of $damage to be subtracted from the previous action, so basically to save the $newhp as $hp.

Comment: Please post your code inline in the question. A reference to some arbitrary site is _not_ a replacement for that. This is clearly explained in the guides here on how to ask. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  Note that there is an `edit` button below the question. _Use it_.

Comment: Search on google "php session"

Answer (score 0):

If possible storing this value in a session variable that will be saved in the browser you use, for more information read here [$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)

```
<?php

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION["hp"]))
    $_SESSION["hp"]=100;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $attack = $_POST['submit'];
    $damage = mt_rand(5, 30);
    $newhp = $_SESSION["hp"] - $damage;
    if ($attkdamage = $_SESSION["hp"] - $damage ) {
        echo "Your HP is:  ". $newhp .  "<br / >";
        echo "You took: " . $damage . " damage!";
    }
    echo "<pre>previus hp " .$_SESSION["hp"];
    $_SESSION["hp"]= $newhp;
    echo "next hp " . $_SESSION["hp"]."</pre>";
}

?>
```